# How to remove user in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have two users in mongodb :

```
{
        "_id" : "admin.mongoAdmin",
        "userId" : UUID("f3000e65"),
        "user" : "mongoAdmin",
        "db" : "admin",
        "roles" : [
                {
                        "role" : "read",
                        "db" : "admin"
                },
                {
                        "role" : "userAdminAnyDatabase",
                        "db" : "admin"
                },
                {
                        "role" : "root",
                        "db" : "admin"
                }
        ],
        "mechanisms" : [
                "SCRAM-SHA-1",
                "SCRAM-SHA-256"
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : "admin.mongoadmin",
        "userId" : UUID("5cf8846e-309f263"),
        "user" : "mongoadmin",
        "db" : "admin",
        "roles" : [
                {
                        "role" : "userAdminAnyDatabase",
                        "db" : "admin"
                },
                {
                        "role" : "dbAdminAnyDatabase",
                        "db" : "admin"
                },
                {
                        "role" : "readWriteAnyDatabase",
                        "db" : "admin"
                }
        ],
        "mechanisms" : [
                "SCRAM-SHA-1",
                "SCRAM-SHA-256"
        ]
}
```

As you see there are two users:

`mongoAdmin` and `mongoadmin` . and I want to remove only "mongoadmin".

**How can I remove only "mongoadmin" ?**

I wonder if `db.dropUser("mongoadmin")` may remove the `mongoAdmin` too because they are the same if we ignore case sensitivity .

Comment: Yes, you can delete it. Usernames are case-sensitive (like almost all identifiers in MongoDB)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `deleteOne` method:

```
db.<CollectionName>.deleteOne( {"userID" : UUID("f3000e65")})
```

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit the `deleteOne` method replaced the deprecated `remove` method in MongoDB v3.2 and can be universally used, while `db.dropUser` method only works with the `system.users` collection. The casing of the method was incorrect in my original answer as it should be `deleteOne`, but aside from that, the above command will work. Additionally, namespace `db.user` should be replaced with `db.<Collection Name>`, which was assumed to be `user` in this case.